# MVC - Exclude View from release deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i need exclude one view from release deploy (controller action + cshtml), I need to do this manually? I want config this funcionality.

thanks.

Comment: What is the need behind not deploying it in release? Would it be possible to just reject roles/users to that controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting the build action to none on the view might help you out here. However, you can't get rid of the controller method

Comment: thx, i use if debug for remove controller action and build none on view